# Debugging failed: vector subscript out of range in PCL "Smoothing and normal estimation based on polynomial reconstruction" tutorial

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, point-cloud-library

I am new to pcl and I am trying to visualize the code from the "Smoothing and normal estimation based on polynomial reconstruction" tutorial and I get this message when I debug it in VS2012 (I'm using pcl 1.7):

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP110D.dll File: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\vector Line: 1140
>
> Expression: vector subscript out of range
>
> For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure,
>   see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

and after I press "Retry" I get another one:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: ...tudio
>   2012\Projects\Tutorials\x64\Debug\pcl_surface_debug.dll File:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\vector
>   Line: 1141
>
> Expression: "Standard C++ Libraries Out of Range" && 0
>
> For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure,
>   see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
>
> (Press Retry to debug the application) The program '[964] MLS.exe' has
>   exited with code 3 (0x3).

then I debugged it line by line it stops at

> mls.process(mls_points);

It also opens the "stdthrow.cpp" :

> ## ifdef _DEBUG
>
> _CRTIMP2_PURE void __CLRCALL_PURE_OR_CDECL _Debug_message(const wchar_t *message, const wchar_t *file, unsigned int line)
>           { // report error and die
>           if(::_CrtDbgReportW(_CRT_ASSERT, file, line, NULL, L"%s", message)==1)
>           {
>               ::_CrtDbgBreak();
>           }
>           }
>   _CRTIMP2_PURE void __CLRCALL_PURE_OR_CDECL _Debug_message(const unsigned short *message, const unsigned short *file, unsigned int
>   line)
>           { // report error and die
>           _Debug_message((wchar_t *) message, (wchar_t *) file, line);
>           }
>
> ## endif

and stops at

> ::_CrtDbgBreak();

Can someone explain the problem? Here is the code from pcl tutorial page:

```html
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/kdtree/kdtree_flann.h>
#include <pcl/surface/mls.h>

int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Load input file into a PointCloud<T> with an appropriate type
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> ());
  // Load bun0.pcd -- should be available with the PCL archive in test 
  pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("bun0.pcd", *cloud);

  // Create a KD-Tree
  pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>);

  // Output has the PointNormal type in order to store the normals calculated by MLS
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal> mls_points;

  // Init object (second point type is for the normals, even if unused)
  pcl::MovingLeastSquares<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointNormal> mls;
 
  mls.setComputeNormals (true);

  // Set parameters
  mls.setInputCloud (cloud);
  mls.setPolynomialFit (true);
  mls.setSearchMethod (tree);
  mls.setSearchRadius (0.03);

  // Reconstruct
  mls.process (mls_points);

  // Save output
  pcl::io::savePCDFile ("bun0-mls.pcd", mls_points);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your KdTree has no input, this will solve your problem:
Add `tree->setInputCloud (cloud);` After`pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>);`

Comment: Could you please add more details about the solution you provided?

Comment: You'd better check the official tutorial:http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/kdtree_search.php#kdtree-search